# Pandas Group By Conditions

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Here is my data -

```
FROM    TO  DIRECTION    AMOUNT  
B    A    IN    100
A    B    OUT    200
A    B    IN    300
B    A    OUT    40
```

As output, I want to show a summary of who paid who in total -

```
FROM    TO    AMOUNT
A    B    300
B    A    340
```

Just to clarify, If A --> B are rows 2 and 1 (`IN` means transfer from `TO` to `FROM`, `OUT` means transfer from `FROM` to `TO`)

I am having trouble going the `.groupby()` way. What I have tried -

```
df.groupby(['FROM', 'TO', 'DIRECTION'])
```

But of course this doesn't seem to cut it. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea is swap values of `FROM` and `TO` by condition:

```
mask = df['DIRECTION'] == 'IN'
df.loc[mask, ['TO', 'FROM']] = df.loc[mask, ['FROM', 'TO']].values
print (df)
  FROM TO DIRECTION  AMOUNT
0    A  B        IN     100
1    A  B       OUT     200
2    B  A        IN     300
3    B  A       OUT      40
```

And then aggregate `sum`:

```
df = df.groupby(['FROM', 'TO'], as_index=False)['AMOUNT'].sum()
print (df)
  FROM TO  AMOUNT
0    A  B     300
1    B  A     340
```

Very similar solution if dont want modify original `DataFrame`:

```
mask = df['DIRECTION'] == 'IN'
df1 = df[['TO','FROM']].mask(mask, df[['FROM','TO']].values)
#output is same like above, only changed order of columns
print (df1)
  TO FROM
0  B    A
1  B    A
2  A    B
3  A    B

df2 = df['AMOUNT'].groupby([df1['FROM'], df1['TO']]).sum().reset_index()
print (df2)
  FROM TO  AMOUNT
0    A  B     300
1    B  A     340
```